# correct Join Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

what would be the right syntax to merge these statements? i am unsure of which join function to use

```
<?php
  $tag_shows_result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                     FROM tags 
                                    WHERE tagname = '$n' 
                                      AND `show` > 0");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tag_shows_result)) {
    $shows_to_tag_result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                          FROM shows 
                                         WHERE id = ".$row['show']." 
                                      ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($shows_to_tag_result)) {
?>
&nbsp;<a href="./show.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><img src="./images/shows/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.jpg" width="150" height="150" border="0" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /></a>   
<?php } } ?>
```

Got it working here is the correct format

```
<?php
$tag_shows_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags JOIN shows ON tags.show = shows.id WHERE tagname='$n' AND `show` > 0 ORDER BY shows.name ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tag_shows_result2))
{
?>
&nbsp;<a href="./show.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><img src="./images/shows/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.jpg" width="150" height="150" border="0" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /></a>   
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: both mysql query results storing is same variable `$row`... not right way

Comment: doesnt matter as the only thing im calling from the first query is the show id which is the same as the show id in the shows table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tags
JOIN shows ON tags.show = shows.id
WHERE tagname='$n' and show>0
```

Guessing at the fields used in the joy, but this should be about what you want.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a5410474/public_html/tags/tag.php on line 80

Comment: why use `*` when you need only two attribute??

Comment: maybe i am using that query again somewhere else in the page to call more info than just those 2...

Answer (score 3):

No need to get fancy:

```
SELECT show.* FROM tags
JOIN shows ON (tags.show = show.id)
WHERE tags.tagname = ?
ORDER BY show.name ASC
```

Or, even simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM shows WHERE id IN (
     SELECT show FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?
) ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: You forgot the ORDER BY clause, but otherwise nice. Perhaps add an example of how to use the prepared statement?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT s.id, s.name FROM `shows` s 
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id=s.show
WHERE t.tagname='$n'AND s.`show` > 0
```

and then display whatever manner u want..

ALL D BEST :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
SELECT tags.id, tags.name
FROM tags, shows
WHERE tags.tagname = '$n' and shows.id = tags.show and tags.show>0
```